# How can we configure Google Custom search using API with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, google-search-api

I would like to use the Google Custom Search API, May i know how can we use it on PHP language. for ex:-

```
<?php
 $keyword = "Demo Test" ;
 $URL = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=demo+test&oq=demo+test&aq=f&aqi=g-s1g5g-v3g-j1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=298789l300162l0l300519l9l9l0l0l0l0l274l1243l0.3.3l6l0" ;
 echo "return number of the website position"; // using method...
 ?>
```

it return the Number of the position of the website. previously we were using as cURL. due to the Google cURL Blockage, we are unable to search on our previous method.

Could you please suggest me any suitable way to configure it ..

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use Google Custom Search on the client's browser?

Comment: actually, we have a method to give the values in Number, if we put the value in $keyword = "demo test". the www.demo.com  on number 3 ... that method return the number "3".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [Google APIs PHP Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/), the following sample application will help you out.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/customSearch/index.php